# How to convert UTC timestamp Value to local date time

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I have a UTC timestamp value 1615958170523 and I want to convert it into our local timezone.

I have tried this method:

The timestamp is in milliseconds that's why firstly I have converted in seconds and then used the below method.

```
$Date = date('m-d-Y H:i:s', 1615958170523/1000);
```

It always returns the time ~6hours ago i.e `03-17-2021 05:16:10` (Considering current time here), I don't want to add +5:30 hours to do the same.

Is it possible that we can use a standard method that means in-built functions which may be provided by Cakephp or PHP so that I can get the answer for the same?

I have also tried this one:

```
$gmtTimezone = new \DateTimeZone('GMT');
$myDateTime = new \DateTime(1615958170523/1000, $gmtTimezone);
```

It returns the same as I have used the `date` function.

Comment: what is your current and expected output?

Comment: try using `UTC` instead of `GMT`

Comment: @InsaneSkull my current output is `03-17-2021 05:16:10` but I want this `03-17-2021 10:46:10`

Comment: @AdarshMohan Tried the `UTC` instead of 'GMT' it provides same  result `2021-03-17 05:16:10.000000` for the above timestamp instead of `03-17-2021 10:46:10`

Comment: What is your local timezone ?

Comment: @Syscall - it's IST GMT+5:30)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the timezone after to define the timestamp in GMT.

```
$timestamp = 1615958170523/1000;

$myDateTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat('U', (int)$timestamp);
echo $myDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), PHP_EOL; // 2021-03-17 05:16:10

$myDateTime->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));
echo $myDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), PHP_EOL; // 2021-03-17 06:16:10

$myDateTime->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('America/Denver'));
echo $myDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), PHP_EOL; // 2021-03-16 23:16:10
```

See [`DateTime::setTimezone()` documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php)

Comment: You could improve the inswer with why the timzone is not applicable when in your case on creating the `DateTime` object.

Comment: @syscall - Thanks! it's working, I also want to know is it possible to get the same date without setting a Timezone?

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://3v4l.org/Ys5Ue)?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [FrozenTime](https://api.cakephp.org/3.9/class-Cake.I18n.FrozenTime.html) which will use the default Timezone you set in your `config/app.php`

Comment: Please consider adding an example of how it can be used to fulfill the needs. If you have a suggestion, you can submit it as a comment. Opinions don't actually provide an answer unless you have a workaround.